Plotting two distributions with contourf in Python
I am trying to recreate this image (somewhat):

I am currently using contourf in Python, however, I am having difficulties plotting both dsitributions in the same image without one of them being more "dominant":

I am currently doing the following:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

# Define the mean and covariance for two different multivariate normal distributions
mean1 = [0, 0]
cov1 = [[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]]

mean2 = [3, 3]
cov2 = [[1, -0.5], [-0.5, 1]]

# Create a grid of (x, y) points
x = np.linspace(-5, 8, 500)
y = np.linspace(-5, 8, 500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pos = np.dstack((X, Y))

# Compute the density of the multivariate normal distributions
rv1 = multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1)
rv2 = multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2)

Z1 = rv1.pdf(pos)
Z2 = rv2.pdf(pos)

# Create the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z1, levels=1000, cmap='Blues', alpha=.5)
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z2, levels=1000, cmap='Blues', alpha=.5)
# plt.gca().set_facecolor('white')  # Set background to white

# plt.title('2D Density Plot of Two Different Multivariate Normal Distributions')
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.show()


Odds are the second plot overlays 50% white. Try plotting the sum of the two densities.

Yes, I think your are right - but how do I solve it :) I have tried several things without any luck..

I've edited my comment: plot the sum instead. Or set the colour of the lowest level to transparent (not sure how).

You could simply plot the average of the two distributions.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np

# Define the mean and covariance for two different multivariate normal distributions
mean1 = [0, 0]
cov1 = [[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]]

mean2 = [3, 3]
cov2 = [[1, -0.5], [-0.5, 1]]

# Create a grid of (x, y) points
x = np.linspace(-5, 8, 500)
y = np.linspace(-5, 8, 500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pos = np.dstack((X, Y))

# Compute the density of the multivariate normal distributions
rv1 = multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1)
rv2 = multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2)

Z1 = rv1.pdf(pos)
Z2 = rv2.pdf(pos)

# Create the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.contourf(X, Y, (Z1 + Z2) / 2, levels=256, cmap='Blues')
plt.show()


PS: If covariant matrices differ a lot, the square root of the determinants could be used as weight:
f1 = np.sqrt(np.abs(np.linalg.det(cov1)))
f2 = np.sqrt(np.abs(np.linalg.det(cov2)))

plt.contourf(X, Y, (f1 * Z1 + f2 * Z2) / (f1 + f2), levels=256, cmap='Blues')


I decided to use seaborn joinplot instead - that work perfectly:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

# Define the mean and covariance for two different multivariate normal distributions
mean1 = [0, 0]
cov1 = [[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]]

mean2 = [3, 3]
cov2 = [[1, -0.5], [-0.5, 1]]

# Generate random samples from the distributions
np.random.seed(0)
samples1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1, size=1000)
samples2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2, size=1000)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([samples1, samples2]), columns=['X', 'Y'])
df1['Dist'] = 1
df1['Dist'].iloc[1000:] = 2

sns.jointplot(data=df1, x="X", y="Y", hue="Dist", kind="kde", space=0, fill=True)
plt.xlim(-5, 8)
plt.ylim(-5, 8)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

# Adjust layout and show plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

